# Is there a way to configure AWS CoPilot Pipeline to source from ECR repository?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codepipeline, amazon-ecr, aws-copilot, aws-copilot-cli

Is there a way to config Pipeline to source from ECR repository rather than selecting one of GitHub, Bitbucket, CodeCommit since my repo is in Gitlab. What are my options to create a CoPilot pipeline?

It would be ideal if something like below is possible.

```
source:
  # The name of the provider that is used to store the source artifacts.
  provider: ECR
  # Additional properties that further specify the location of the artifacts.
  properties:
    tag: latest
    repository: <erc-repository-url>
```

Reference: https://aws.github.io/copilot-cli/docs/concepts/pipelines/